# Can you use a Martial Discipline Stance from Path of War during underwater combat?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, underwater, path-of-war

Can you use a Martial Discipline Stance from Path of War during underwater combat?

Specifically Thrashing Dragon Stance: Outer Sphere Stance - When wielding two weapons, disciple inflicts an additional 1d6 points of damage per attack, -2 to AC.

Comment: #William Porter - Sorry, I put the wrong tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, of course. There is absolutely nothing anywhere that suggests you cannot. *Path of War* is based on 3.5e’s *Tome of Battle*, where the Stone Dragon discipline could only be used on solid ground—this was nigh-universally considered a mistake, and not one *Path of War* repeated.

Ultimately, though, I cannot recommends strongly enough that you avoid underwater combat in Pathfinder. The rules are cumbersome and awkward, and do not work well.